# when running spark-submit on yarn then error?

Tags: pyspark, spark-submit

### I sent it and the warning hung

**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tobKT.png)**

### when I check in port 8088 then notification

`Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply from uat-bigdata-masternode:30002 in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47) at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62) at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58) at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38) at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:234) at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recover$1(Future.scala:395) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33) at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64) at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.execute(ThreadUtils.scala:99) at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$4.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:138) at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:53) at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:52) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:187) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33) at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64) at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:82) at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85) at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:59) at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:875) at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110) at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:107) at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:873) at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288) at scala.concurrent.Promise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112) at scala.concurrent.Promise.tryFailure$(Promise.scala:112) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:187) at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:214) at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)`

fix help me! Thanks

Comment: help me i really need it